# How do I write a function that limits user's input?

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I use tkinter in python. I want to write a function that allows the user to input digits, from 1 to 6, to 6 entries. User is allowed to write only one digit in each entry. Digits cannot repeat themselves, meaning user has to delete digit X from an entry before they can put it in another entry. I control if the digit is already being used by using a list. If a digit wasn't used, it's displayed and added to the list. If it was used, it's not displayed. However, I don't understand how to remove from the list the digit that was removed by the user from one of the entries. I need to do so so the digit can be used again in another entry bracket.

I tried to gather values from the entries, using .get() method, and create a list of the values that were put in entries. I then compare the list of values to the list of used digits and make them equal, but it doesn't work. Any suggestions? I think regex works fine - I can insert only digits from 1 to 6. However, after removing them, I cannot insert them again.

entered_numbers - a list that controls what digit has been used
values_no_bio - a list that contains values from the entries where the user input a digit.

```py
entered_numbers= []

def validate_input_no(text):
    if text == "":
        return True
    elif re.match("^[1-6]$", text) is not None:
        number = str(text)
        if number not in entered_numbers:
            entered_numbers.append(number)
            return True
        if number in entered_numbers:
            return False
    values_no_bio = [ent.get() for ent in entry_list_no_bio]
    entered_numbers = values_no_bio
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex is overkill here, you can just store the allowed values and check against them. I'm using `set`s here instead of `list`s because `set`s don't care about order. You can call `entered_numbers.remove("5")` to remove items from a set (it will throw an exception if the item is not in the set).

```
allowed = {str(i) for i in range(1, 7)}
entered_numbers = set()


def validate_input_no(text):
    if not text:
        return True
    elif text in allowed
        if number not in entered_numbers:
            entered_numbers.add(number)
            return True
        else:
            return False
    values_no_bio = {ent.get() for ent in entry_list_no_bio}
    entered_numbers = values_no_bio
    return False
```